# Does CatBoost support L1 regularization of the cost function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, regularized, catboost

Does CatBoost suppport L1 regularization? The hyper parameter l2_leaf_reg controls the L2 regularization  term of the cost function, but is there any way to use the L1 norm?

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the documentation it doesn't seem like it
[Catboost reference params](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_parameters-list.html)

I guess if you are interested in L1 to perform feature selection, a possible solution would be to run Lightgbm or XGBoost first with L1 regularization to get the relevant subset of features and then pass those to Catboost